# Transforming a coordinate array in row into a coordinate table

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I need to create an output transformation (select) for a row containing `structure-01`

| attribute | value |
| --- | --- |
| structure | {{10, 17.158}, {11, 18.569}} |
| structure-01 | [[1, 18.65], [2, 18.95], [3, 19.86]] |

The expected result:

| x | y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 18.65 |
| 2 | 18.95 |
| 3 | 19.86 |

I need the equivalent of the following query, which I have for `structure`

```
SELECT
    jsonb_array_elements->>0 AS x,
    jsonb_array_elements->>1 AS y
FROM(
select jsonb_array_elements(to_jsonb(value::text[]))
FROM public.market_data
WHERE "attribute" IN ('structure')) as subquery
```

**DLL**

```
CREATE TABLE public.market_data (
    "attribute" text NOT NULL,
    value text NULL,
    CONSTRAINT market_data_pk PRIMARY KEY (attribute)
);
```

**Database**: Postgresql

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first structure is a textual representation of PostgreSQL array. In your SQL you are treating it as such ( `value::text[]` ) and latter convert it to jsonb type and use jsonb functions and operators for your goal. While it is unnecessary you are free to do it.

The structure `structure-01` is a textual representation of json array. So the only thing to change is the way you treat the `value`:

```
SELECT
    jsonb_array_elements->>0 AS x,
    jsonb_array_elements->>1 AS y
FROM(
select jsonb_array_elements(value::jsonb)
FROM public.market_data
WHERE "attribute" IN ('structure-01')) as subquery;
```

Notice the `value::jsonb` it treats `value` as a jsonb

See test case in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/380z6Fxz).